# How to customize bootstrap switch color

Tags: css, customization, bootstrap-switch

How can I customize bootstrap switch color to the desired color?

I found a `oncolor` and `offcolor` but not know how to change them.

Answer (score 25):

According to [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20161121011300/http://www.bootstrap-switch.org:80/methods.html) every option is also a method. So you can apply onColor and OffColor like that:

```
$("#sw").bootstrapSwitch({onColor: 'danger'});
```

or like that:

```
$("#sw").bootstrapSwitch();
...
$("#sw").bootstrapSwitch('onColor', 'danger');
```

or to override the default options of the library:

```
$.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onColor = 'danger';
```

To use your own colors you need to create your own CSS class. For example, this class uses 'retroorange' name with your color:

```
.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-retroorange,
.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-retroorange {
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff9933;
}
```

Then you can use `'retroorange'` in the usual way like that:

```
$("#sw").bootstrapSwitch({onColor: 'retroorange'});
```

Comment: Thanks @alemv
But I want to use my own colors, like this one: #ff9933!

Comment: I added a method how to use your own colors to my answer.

Comment: So I should use css defined classes?

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js#L265

Comment: this is pretty irritating, having to define classes. To do this dynamically, I end up having to dynamically inject style tags within my code. Was that really necessary?

Comment: The link to bootstrap-switch.org is no longer valid. It either goes to a domain placeholder or, sometimes, to an evil "Your Flash plug-in is out of date" page.